# Javascript Script parsing values onto JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

So I have a Javascript script (don't judge it, i've barely used the technology before and this is in need of a tidy!)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    retrieveComments();
});


function retriveComments(){
        videoID = readCookie("currentVideoID");
        $.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" +videoID+ "/comments", function(d){

    $(d).find("entry").each(function(){

        var $entry = $(this);
        var author = $entry.attr("author");
        var comment = $entry.find("content").text();

        var html = '<div class="videoComments">';
        html += '<p class="author">" + author + "</p>';
        html += '<p class="comment"> " + comment + "</p>';
        html += '</div>'; 

   };
   $('#comments').append(html);
    });
```

And I wish to retrieve the values author and content (comment), and display it on the page. Examples I have found over the course of the day have shown 2 seperate files one with the script in and one a .jsp with the page content in, then class tags (?) corresponding to the last line (in my case #comments).

Seeing as I don't need any other content than just the data I've retrieved and the content I've built in the script, I have this:

```
<div id="comments"> </div>
```

but it doesn't display, and I can't see what I have different hin my case.

My whole page looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoID = readCookie("currentVideoID");

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        retrieveComments();
    });


function retriveComments(){
        videoID = readCookie("currentVideoID");
        $.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" +videoID+ "/comments", function(d){

        $(d).find("entry").each(function(){

            var $entry = $(this);
            var author = $entry.attr("author");
            var comment = $entry.find("content").text();

            var html = '<div class="videoComments">';
            html += '<p class="author">" + author + "</p>';
            html += '<p class="comment"> " + comment + "</p>';
            html += '</div>'; 

       };
       $('#comments').append(html);
       });

});
</script>
<h1>TEST</h1>

<div id="comments"> </div>
```

Any ideas how I can get that HTML to display?

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.append()` as you want to generate html from a String and not simply insert html objects

Comment: Open the console, there are a bunch of syntax errors, closings in the wrong places, the function name is not the same as the function you are calling in the document ready function etc. mismatched quotes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the `readCookie` function does (I assume it reads a cookie), but here it is without all the syntax errors and working:

```
$(document).ready(retriveComments);

function retriveComments() {
    $.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/jofNR_WkoCE/comments", function (d) {
        $(d).find("entry").each(function (_, entry) {
            var author  = $(entry).find("author name").text(),
                comment = $(entry).find("content").text();
                html    = '<div class="videoComments">';

            html += '<p class="author">' + author + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="comment">' + comment + '</p>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#comments').append(html);
        });
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/2/)

Comment: If you're familiar with CQ5, it's to do with that. This 'page' is actually a component, VideoID is stored in the cookie when the full page is loaded.

Comment: Then just add the videoID, I removed it and found a random Youtube ID to get some comments.

Comment: How was I going wrong? Was it just the mismatched quotes etc?!

Comment: Compare the above code to the one in your question and you'll see what the problem was, and yes, syntax errors mostly.